GEMINI API session management
Is there any way to keep track of sessions of interactions with Gemini API like I can ask follow-up questions through API calls. I am making a website in react where I want to integrate this feature. And since the interactions can go quite long so I can't copy paste previous chats for context of specific call.
I researched about this but everywhere I found that an API call is a new session every time and that's what I don't want. I want to continue sessions somewhere like chatting or like how we interact with gemini on it's website through API calls.

enjoy https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/get-started/tutorial?lang=node#multi-turn-conversations-chat

Gemini api does not hold any session data.
You need to send the relevant history with each call there is currently no way around this with the exception of files.
If you are sending files along with your prompt if you upload them to the file api they will remain for two days and you will get a url back you can send that url with your history then without having to reupload the file.
However this does not change the size of the context window.
